# Angular - formatting a Date to make http call

Tags: angular, typescript, date, http, format

I'm trying to implement server-side filtering by date in a table. I've got a [matDatePicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) that allows me to choose a certain date. As soon as i click it, an http call is made and the data from it is put in the table.

The http call should look like this:

`https://bgpie.net/api/rrc/00/sequence?limit=20&minStartDate=2021-05-19T22:00:00.000Z&page=1`

but it looks like this:

`https://bgpie.net/api/rrc/00/sequence?page=1&limit=10&minStartDate=Thu%20May%2020%202021%2000:00:00%20GMT+0200%20(Central%20European%20Summer%20Time)`

Whenever I use the matDatePicker the component's property `startDate!: Date` is updated, in this case it gets updated to `Thu May 20 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)`. This value translates to the one above when i put it in as an HttpParameter like this:

```
findSequences(pageIndex: number, pageSize: number, rrc: string, startDate: Date): Observable<PaginatedResult>{
      let params = new HttpParams();
      params = params.append('page', pageIndex.toString());
      params = params.append('limit', pageSize.toString());      
      params = params.append('minStartDate', startDate.toString());
      return this.http.get<PaginatedResult>('https://bgpie.net/api/rrc/' + rrc + '/sequence', { params});
}
```

Comment: Use `startDate.toISOString()`, that should do the trick

Comment: thank you, works perfectly. If you want you can post an answer and I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you are looking for is the ISO date format.

Use `startDate.toISOString()` and it should be good